# How to represent fractions in html

Tags: html, fractions

I want to represent fractions in html and the code I am using now is this:

```
<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

But I want to represent it something like this:

[image]

How do I change it?

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: I want it in html code for it. any idea.

Comment: Nope, you cannot achieve this in pure HTML until you tweak that using CSS, let me know if you need that

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks for the clarification. I wanted it in pure html. Using css will be a option. But wanted it in pure html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible through pure HTML. But you can create that type of fraction using a bit of CSS.

```css
.fraction {
  position: relative;
  width: 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.numerator {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.denominator {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  width: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fraction">
  <div class="numerator">3</div>
  <div class="denominator">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the vertical line in the denominator mean?

Comment: I am not sure about that. But the OP wanted something like that. @lakesh Care to clarify?

Comment: @cars10 http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LongDivision.html Long division matches up to some extent :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use mathjax. It's the defacto library for math rendering. However, it is not lightweight. Note that google chose *not* to support mathml

Alternately, use html/css.  A fraction is just two divs stacked on top of each other with a border in the middle.