# Writing Text beside Fractions in html

Tags: html, css

I previously asked this qn:[How to represent fractions in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773796/how-to-represent-fractions-in-html). It was about writing the numerator and denominator in html and the solution provided allows me to write fraction in the proper format.

However, I can't write text beside it. If I write text beside it, it appears together at the top or bottom. It appears below it. I want the text to appear beside it.

The code is here:

```
.fraction {
  position: relative;
  width: 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.numerator {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.denominator {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  width: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
}

<div class="fraction">
  <div class="numerator">3</div>
  <div class="denominator">8</div>
</div>
```

The text appears like this:

[image]

Is there any solution? Any solution?

Comment: like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/e9nc6gna/)???

Comment: but you need write into div fraction or out ??

Answer (score 1):

Set .fraction class display property as inline-block.
I guess you also will have to fiddle with its vertical-align prop.

Answer (score 0):

add these css -

```
.fraction {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/et2Lan5k/

Answer (score 0):

Add div word  and set CSS
CSS:

```
.fraction {
    position: relative;
    width: 1em;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.numerator {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
.denominator {
    width: 0.75em;
    text-align: center;
}
.word{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    line-height:2.5em;
    left:1em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fraction">
    <div class="numerator">3</div>
    <div class="denominator">8</div>
    <div class="word">HI</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e9nc6gna/1/

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with just a few lines of code :

Wrap the numerator and denominator within `<span>` tags.
Wrap them again within a container `<span>`.
Then declare the container `inline-block`, so that it stays on a single line.
Declare the `vertical-align: middle` property for the container.
Add a border at the bottom of the numerator (or at the top of the denominator) so that it looks like a fraction.

Use this code :

```css
* {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.container {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.numerator {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
33<span class="container"><span class="numerator">1</span><br><span>3</span></span>
```

Also, do not put line breaks in between these tags, otherwise, there would be unnecessary spaces within the fraction, since the `<span>` tags are declared as inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code if you wish.

```
<style type="text/css">

    frac {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        vertical-align: middle;
        letter-spacing: 0.001em;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    frac num { /*Numerator*/
        display: block;
        padding: 0.01em;
    }
    
    frac den { /*Denominator*/
        border-top: thin solid black;
     /* Above line is for the division line. */
    }

</style>
```

```
<p>33<frac><num>1</num><den>3</den></frac> sss</p>
```

If you want to change `font-size`, then add a `font-size` tag inside the `frac` tag.